# Scala/Lift: How to parse json to a case class?

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

We query an api with a list of items. Their response comes back giving status for each item like this:

```
{"Results":[
  {"item1":{"status": "whatever1", "cid":"blah1"}},
  {"item2":{"status": "whatever2", "cid":"blah2"}}
]}
```

`item1` and `item2` are ids that we use to query.
I need to extract a simple list of `class class Item(itemId: String, status: String, cid: String)`.

How do I do this?

We use Lift json which allows to convert to case classes if the fields are known, but in this case the fields are item ids themselves, so I am a little lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact format returned by the API? It's not valid JSON. The `"key":{value}` pairs would have to be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: @JoeK: I am sorry. That was a typo.

Comment: Lift allows to create custom serializers. That will help